# How to check if PostgreSQL schema exists using SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am using SQLAlchemy to generate tables in a specific schema in a PostgreSQL database. If the schema does not exist, I want to create it. I know the PostgreSQL query to check for the existence of the schema:

```
SELECT exists(select schema_name FROM information_schema.schemata WHERE schema_name = 'foo')
```

but I want to know how I should handle this using SQLAlchemy.

Answer (score 6):

@javax's answer is almost correct; the following is a little clarification:

```
q = exists(select([("schema_name")]).select_from("information_schema.schemata")
    .where("schema_name = 'foo'"))
if not session.query(q).scalar():
    session.execute('CREATE SCHEMA foo;')
```

Comment: If you get some warnings (eg: python 3.6.6 sqlalchemy 1.0) like: `Textual column expression 'schema_name' should be explicitly declared with text('schema_name'), or use column('schema_name') for more specificity (this warning may be suppressed after 10 occurrences)`. To avoid just wrap with `text()` each string. 
ie:
`q = exists(select([(text("schema_name"))]).select_from(text("information_schema.schemata")).where(text("schema_name = 'foo'")))`

Answer (score 4):

If you want to integrate it with SQLAlchemy you could use [reflection](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/schema.html#metadata-reflection) but for an easier and quicker solution:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import exists, select
exists(select([("schema_name")]).select_from("information_schema.schemata").
       where("schema_name == 'foo'"))
```

This will return `True` or `False`.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using MySQL and this works for me (with sqlalchemy v1.4.1, python 3.9.1):

```
import sqlalchemy as sa

engine = sa.create_engine("mysql+pymysql://someuser:somepassword@somehost")
inspector = sa.inspect(engine)
myschema = "someschema"
if myschema in inspector.get_schema_names():
    print(f"{myschema} schema exists")
```

and if you want to create a schema if it doesn't exist:

```
if myschema not in inspector.get_schema_names():
    engine.execute(sa.schema.CreateSchema(myschema))
    # optional. set the default schema to the new schema:
    engine.dialect.default_schema_name = myschema
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been using this with Postgres, though was surprised to learn that `IF NOT EXISTS` is not part of the SQL standard -

```
engine.execute('CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS foo;')
```

Apparently it's an extension for Postgres and MySQL - https://www.w3resource.com/sql/sql-basic/create-schema.php

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Finds if a schema exists using pure SqlAlchemy:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import event
from sqlalchemy.schema import CreateSchema, DropSchema
...
engine = create_engine(dbstr)
meta = ModelBase()
...
if not engine.dialect.has_schema(engine, schema=schema_name):
    event.listen(meta.metadata, 'before_create', CreateSchema(schema_name))

meta.metadata.reflect(bind=engine, schema=schema_name)
meta.metadata.create_all(engine, checkfirst=True)
```