# SQLAlchemy: "create schema if not exists"

Tags: python, sql, database, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I want to do the "CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS" query in SQLAlchemy.
Is there a better way than this:

```
    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(connstr)

    schema_name = config.get_config_value('db', 'schema_name')

    #Create schema; if it already exists, skip this
    try:
        engine.execute(CreateSchema(schema_name))
    except sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError:
        pass
```

I am using Python 3.5.

Comment: Well you have not mentioned which db you are using. At the moment I cannot see anything in sqlalchemy but sure we can run raw ddl query. For example, in case of postgres db we can execute something like `engine.execute('CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS schema_name')`

Comment: I am using PostgreSQL at the moment but this is meant to be used by multiple databases in the future. Thats why I didnt use psycopg2 or any other database-specific tool - because I thougt I can just change the connstr variable for each database and SQLAlchemy will create schema in that particular database.

Comment: Am I wrong? Doesnt SQLAlchemy work like this?

Comment: Well it will work in the same way only thing is it will throw Programming exception if it already exists. If you can gracefully handle it then Sqlalchemy will be able to create schema on the fly.

Comment: Also you can have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18346076/how-to-check-if-postgresql-schema-exists-using-sqlalchemy

Comment: The try/except approach is better than the look before you leap approaches in the answers, since they have an implicit race condition: another process could create the schema between checking for its existence and creation.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I had the same question and the answer, which I found, is:

```
if not engine.dialect.has_schema(engine, schema_name):
    engine.execute(sqlalchemy.schema.CreateSchema(schema_name))
```

We can also check schema without engine instance, but using connection

```
conn = engine.connect()
if conn.dialect.has_schema(conn, schema_name):
    ...
```

Comment: You are missing `not` in the `conn` example if clause: `if not conn.dialect.has_schema`.

Comment: You can also import the method as such: `from sqlalchemy.schema import CreateSchema`. And use it directly with `engine.execute(CreateSchema(schema_name))`.

Comment: re `has_schema`: `NotImplementedError: This method is not implemented for SQLAlchemy 2.0.`

Comment: @joel, you can use Inspector instead, it has the same method: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/reflection.html#sqlalchemy.engine.reflection.Inspector.has_schema

Answer (score 7):

For MS Sql users, there's no `has_schema()` but this seems to work:

```
if schemaname not in conn.dialect.get_schema_names(conn):
   conn.execute(schema.CreateSchema(schemaname))
```

Answer (score 7):

Since version 2.0 of SQLAlchemy there's available `if_not_exists` parameter for the [`CreateSchema`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/ddl.html#sqlalchemy.schema.CreateSchema) class.

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.schema import CreateSchema

connectable = create_engine("postgresql+psycopg2://postgres@localhost/postgres")

with connectable.connect() as connection:
    connection.execute(CreateSchema("new_schema", if_not_exists=True))
    connection.commit()
```

Also there is available [`has_schema`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/reflection.html#sqlalchemy.engine.reflection.Inspector.has_schema) method for `Inspector` objects (created with [`inspect`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/inspection.html#sqlalchemy.inspect) method) which can be used as a dialect-agnostic interface for database metadata to check existence of schema. Maybe you can find it usable in some situations.

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, inspect
from sqlalchemy.schema import CreateSchema

schema = "new_schema"
connectable = create_engine("postgresql+psycopg2://postgres@localhost/postgres")

with connectable.connect() as connection:
    if not inspect(connection).has_schema(schema):
        connection.execute(CreateSchema(schema))
        connection.commit()
```

Answer (score 3):

My preferred way of doing that task:

```
from sqlalchemy import inspect
<You might need a few more SQLAlchemy imports

def setup_schemas(engine, metadata):
    inspector = inspect(engine)
    all_schemas = inspector.get_schema_names()
    for schema in metadata._schemas:
        if schema not in all_schemas:
            _create_schema(engine, schema)
    
def _create_schema(engine, schema) -> None:
    stmt = text(f"CREATE SCHEMA {schema}")
    with engine.connect() as conn:
        conn.execute(stmt)
        conn.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the excellent [`sqlalchemy_utils`](https://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.io/) package to do just that, in a very neat way.

First, install the package:

```py
pip install sqlalchemy_utils
```

Then use it like this:

```py
from sqlalchemy_utils.functions import database_exists, create_database

engin_uri = 'postgres://postgres@localhost/name'

if not database_exists(engin_uri):
    create_database(engin_uri)
```

The example from the official docs has used PostgreSQL and I have personally used it on MySQL 8.

Comment: Your example show how to create a database not a schema. The OP wants to know a better way than his to create a specific schema

Comment: @sdikby I can confirm that this example works for MySQL as well. database and schema describe the same entity in MySQL