# How to create a table with schema in SQLModel?

Tags: python, database, postgresql, schema, sqlmodel

I want to create a table with schema `"fooschema"` and name `"footable"`. Based on [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/tiangolo/sqlmodel/issues/20) and to some extent the docs, I tried

```
fooMetadata = MetaData(schema="fooschema")

class Foo(SQLModel, table=True):
    __tablename__ = "footable"
    metadata = fooMetadata

    id_: int = Field(primary_key=True)

engine = create_engine("<url>")

Foo.metadata.create_all(engine)
with Session(engine) as session:
    row = Foo(id_=0)
    session.add(row)
    session.commit()
    session.refresh(row)
```

and tried replacing `metadata = fooMetadata` with `__table_args__ = {"schema": "fooSchema"}`, and replacing `Foo.metadata.create_all` with `SQLModel.metadata.create_all` but I'm always getting an error like

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable) relation "fooschema.footable" does not exist
```

or

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.InvalidSchemaName) schema "fooschema" does not exist
```

Oddly `__table_args__` works for reading an existing table, just not creating it.

Comment: Well, does that schema exist already? I doubt SQLAlchemy will just create one for you _implicitly_.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg no, but with the name `create_all`, I thought it might, well, create all, especially since the metadata explicitly includes the schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by explicitly creating the schema with

```
    with engine.connect() as connection:
        connection.execute(CreateSchema("fooschema"))
        connection.commit()
```

*Note this is sort of answered in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55345404/5986907) but it's not particularly clear and this question is about SQLModel specifically.*

Comment: Remember that SQLModel is essentially still just a thin wrapper around SQLAlchemy (and Pydantic), which means that fundamental DB operations are almost always the same as with SQLAlchemy. Unless there is a built-in mechanism in SQLAlchemy to implicitly create missing schemas, I highly doubt that SQLModel will support that anytime soon.